# Finding streamline equation

Tags: calculus, integration

> Find the equation for the streamline following the vector field $$v(x,y) = 8x\textbf{i} + (9x+16y)\bf{j}$$ which passes through the point $(1,18)$. Write the equation in the form $y = f(x)$.

I started out with $$\frac{dx}{8x} = \frac{dy}{9x+16y} \implies \frac98 + \frac{2y}x = \frac{dy}{dx} $$  Not sure how to continue from this.

Comment: Since it passes thru $(1,18)$ don't you know it must be positive?

Comment: Couldn't it pass through any number of points with negative $y$-values as well? Regardless, that gives me $$ y = \sqrt{\frac{2592.5-\frac12x^2}{8}}$$ which seems to be an incorrect answer.

Comment: I didn't check your integration, but let's assume you're right. If you had a leading negative sign, then the square root would need to produce a negative result to give $18$. The square by convention doesn't produce negative values so it's impossible.

Comment: Ah yeah that makes sense. I guess I must have made a mistake somewhere else then.

Comment: Updated the post so it's more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you got linear ODE

of form $\dfrac{dy}{dx}+Py=Q$

$P=\dfrac{-2}{x}\implies I.F(integrating factor)=\dfrac{1}{x^2}$

$\dfrac{y}{x^{2}}=\dfrac{9}{8}.\displaystyle\int \dfrac{1}{x^2} dx+C$

$\dfrac{y}{x^2}=-\dfrac{9}{8x}+C$

since, it pass through$(1,18)$

$\dfrac{y}{x^2}=-\dfrac{9}{8x}+\dfrac{153}{8}$